# Setting plot min and max

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a data set in R and am wanting to set min and max for my y-axis. It isn't showing 0, and I want it to. I've had to use a 
`scale_y_log10` and am wondering how I add limits to this. I did try adding `limits = c(?,?)` but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code for reference if needed

```
ggplot(data = rc_data, aes(x = t, y = Vc))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Time (sec)",
       y = "Voltage (V) , Log Scale") +
  ggtitle("Drop of Voltage of a Capacitor")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(rc_data$t), max(rc_data$t), by = 5),1)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = round(seq(0, max(rc_data$Vc)+0.5, by = 0.2),1))
```

Comment: You're trying to pass `0`  to `log10()` which  returns negative infinite

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your own *log10*, then plot, after that we can set limits to *yaxis*, see example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# example data
df1 <- mtcars[ , c("mpg", "disp")]
df1$disp_log10 <- log10(df1$disp)

ggplot(data = df1, aes(mpg, disp_log10))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(df1$disp_log10)))
```

[image]